# paypal personal credit card payment workaround

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

we are in Europe and actually, the guest payments (using credit/debit cards) to a friend aren't allowed. 
We are searching an alternative to avoid the paypal registration (we known the limitations of this payment type https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/guest-payments).

We are thinking the next workaround: (using chained payment):

```
          [fee 1]                             [fee 2]
Guest   ------------>   Primary receiver  -------------> Secondary receiver
(credit card)          (business account)                 (personal account)
```

So the Primary receiver don't get any money, transfers all the receiver money to Secondary receiver.

The problem is that, when you create the receivers list, you must specify the amount of Primary and Secondary receiver, if we set feesPayer to SECONDARYONLY, we don't know which is the exact amount, because we unknow the amount of fees (fee 1 + fee 2).

We have saw the "Payments Details API Operation", to try to get the fees from PayKey and then complete the payrequest message, but this information doesn't return in the message.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chained Payments the primary receiver receives the total amount of the payment. Once the primary receives the payments then up to that total amount can be split amongst the other recipients.

For this example a consumer makes a $100.00 payment:

Primary receiver receives $100.00

Primary receiver then automatically forwards the funds to:

- Secondary receiver 1 $50.00
- Secondary receiver 2 $30.00
- Secondary receiver 3 $20.00

This is fine as long as the secondary receiver's collective amount doesn't exceed the primary receivers amount. This should also take care of the fee issue as the secondary receiver who has all the funds are responsible for the fees for both transactions.

You are correct in not knowing the fee amount prior to the transaction. This is calculated by PayPal while payment is being made and there is no option for seeing the possible fee prior to payment. If you are the owner of the receiving accounts you may perform the calculations as you are already aware of the rates being charged.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you Matt, so it's posible to set a chained transaction like this:

Comment: Primary receiver amount = 100$, Secondary receiver amount = 100$, and finally the secondary receiver receives 100$ - fees ? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is, please keep in mind the secondary receiver will pay the fees for both the transaction to the primary receiver and to it's own account.

Comment: I have done a test in sandbox and works perfectly. Thanks a lot.