# Paypal MPL for Android and Pizza example "Application not authorized,Error ID -1"

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I downloaded this library:[MPL](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/blob/gh-pages/MPL/PayPal_MPL_1.5.6.46_Android-Developer-Package.zip)

I downloaded this example: [PizzaMPL](https://github.com/paypal/tech-talks/tree/master/AndroidDevCamp-March2011)

I created a sandbox account and several Personal and business accounts.

I can see perfectly the API credentials and signature (I don't need API credentials for testing in SANDBOX?) If yes, where I have to put in my code?? The docs says that "In addition to the API credentials, MPL calls also require an AppID. For the PayPal Sandbox, the AppID is static: "APP-80W284485P519543T"" In adition ????

Now in the SANDBOX environment, when I give the button "pay with paypal", the code obtained in PayPalActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) is: PayPal.FAILURE and the message displayed is: "Application not authorized,Error ID -1"

I have not been able to find this error in the wonderful documentation of paypal.

Here My code:

```
public void initLibrary() {
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();

    if (pp == null) {            
        pp = PayPal.initWithAppID(this, "APP-80W284485P519543T",
                PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

        pp.setLanguage("en_US");
        pp.setFeesPayer(PayPal.FEEPAYER_EACHRECEIVER);
        pp.setShippingEnabled(true);
        pp.setDynamicAmountCalculationEnabled(false);
        _paypalLibraryInit = true;
    }
}

private void showPayPalButton() {

    // Generate the PayPal checkout button and save it for later use
    PayPal pp = PayPal.getInstance();
    CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = pp.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
    // The OnClick listener for the checkout button
    launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    // Add the listener to the layout
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    params.bottomMargin = 10;
    launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    launchPayPalButton.setId(12345);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.wrapper)).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
}


public void PayPalButtonClick(View arg0) {
    // Create a basic PayPal payment
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();
    payment.setCurrencyType("USD");        
    payment.setRecipient("erauskin-facilitator@gmail.com");        
    payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(200.0f));        
    payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_PERSONAL);        
    payment.setMerchantName("Discográfica XXX");        
    Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this);
    this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
}

public void PayPalActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            // The payment succeeded
            String payKey = intent
                    .getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
            this.paymentSucceeded(payKey);
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            // The payment was canceled
            this.paymentCanceled();
            break;
        case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
            // The payment failed -- we get the error from the
            // EXTRA_ERROR_ID and EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE
            String errorID = intent
                    .getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
            String errorMessage = intent
                    .getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            this.paymentFailed(errorID, errorMessage);
        }
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest you use the [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/)?  MPL will be deprecated once the new Android SDK reaches feature parity.

Comment: Thanks for the coment, but we're outside the U.S., and we have to use adaptative Payments. I think is not posible with the new SDK right?

Comment: Which features in Adaptive Payments do you require?  See the [mSDK overview](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/mobile-sdk-overview/) for specific information on which features are not yet supported.

Comment: We need user1 pay money to user2 in our app, and cording to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129105/paypal-personal-payments-in-live-mode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185357/paypal-personal-credit-card-payment-workaround, we decides to use Adaptative Payments. We try new SDK, works well for single pays, but you can`t change transación type to PERSONAL.

Comment: If you have a business account, you can accept payments in many countries. Please see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Comment: The question is not about that...

Comment: hi guys i am trying to use paypal to pay money to my users from my application once they have completed a certain task. should i be using  mpl? how do i go about this? i could not find the feature in the android sdk.

Comment: @Junanjo: Have you find any solution. because i am facing same issue for transfer to Third party. and Android Paypal not support currently Third party transaction

Comment: @Juanjo did you find any solution.